# Why does my attempt to PATCH a Firestore record replace the entire document?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, php-curl

I'm writing a PHP script using cURL to update a few fields in a Firestore document via the Firestore REST API. My problem is that when I run the script, it's replacing the entire document with the fields I'm trying to update as if it's simply doing a PUT. Can someone help me out with this PHP snippet?

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PATCH'),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'cURL',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here to make this be perceived as a PATCH from Firestore? Is there any decent way to find out what Firestore is receiving from my script?

Comment: For the time being, I've worked around it by first GETting the whole document, changing the values that need updates, and PUTting it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its an old question but still want to address this issue. You need to pass `updatedMask` parameter in order to merge with existing document as referenced [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch#query-parameters), else its going to replace the entire document with the payload you send.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for solving this mystery for me!