# How to incrementally apply Immer patch(es) to a firestore doc?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, immer.js, immer

I have an app that uses Immer for handling state, with patches/inverse patches being used and stored for undo+document history. I would like to use the patches generated by Immer's produce function to update a portion of a Firestore doc, but I cannot find an easy way to do this without writing the different cases out ("add", "replace", "delete", etc) and recursively stitching string names of paths together; it all feels rather clunky.  I searched online quite a bit for prior work, but I could only find https://github.com/tdawes/immer-to-firestore, which was last updated 3 years ago, and that being the sole example of exactly what I'm trying to do makes me perhaps there is a reason I cannot find anyone else doing it?  Am I missing something?

(Side rant: I asked Bing Chat to help me, and while it missed the entire point of what I was asking, it very cheerfully produced some code that didn't help me at all [sigh].  When I further asked about applying inverse patches, it very enthusiastically and confidently told me we could easily do that too, and proceeded to rename one of the variables in its prior code to "inverse patches", lol.)

I thought it would be easy to find examples of converting Immer patches to update storage like in Firebase. I am currently replacing my entire Firebase doc whenever there is any change, but I'd like to just change the portion of the doc affected by the Immer patch.
My code looks like:

```
setDocument(produce(document,
  (draft) => { 
    draft.newField = "foo" 
  }, 
  (patches, inversePatches) => {
patches.forEach(patch=>{
   console.log(patch); 
   /* here is where I want to update the firestore doc
with firestoreApp.collection("items").doc(document.id).update(data), 
but "data" should be just the portion of the original document
that is affected by the Immer patch */
}
))
```

// currently I replace the entire document, which seems less than ideal

```
useEffect(() => {firestoreApp.collection("items").doc(document.id).update(document)},[document])
```

Comment: So, I was muddling about with how to handle data in my Lit-based application, which also uses Firestore. Indeed there seems to be no prior work, but basically it seems to me this is because Firestore is simply not useful in this way. SQL updates can touch a given column and not care about the contents of other columns, but Firestore only deals in entire documents. It is just not useful in this way. I mean, you could store patches in Firestore, then pull them out again and apply them. I'm not sure what the value is.

Comment: Actually I looked at the github repo you mentioned. I think the author is confusing 'firebase' and 'firestore' (the realtime database vs the newer firestore database). Google has rather confusing terminology. FIREBASE, the realtime database, does have object mutation, basically your data is just a monstrous huge JSON object, conceptually, and you can mutate it. So patches DO make sense there! They make no sense for Firestore, where each document is an atomic entity.

Comment: Thanks, Tod. You are right about my confusing firestore and firebase terminology. 
To your point about firebase: doing a quick search on this topic again (where my own SO question was the 2nd result), I found a more recent article: https://colinchjs.github.io/2023-09-29/00-14-20-202068-using-immer-with-firebase-integrating-immer-into-a-firebase-project/.
But I'm not sure it's necessary, and I've pursued other directions for now.

Comment: Also I believe patching a firestore doc is a real thing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789344/why-does-my-attempt-to-patch-a-firestore-record-replace-the-entire-document?rq=2